# VBA - PB with loop

Tags: vba, loops, row

I code a loop which is picking values in worksheets and summurising them into one. 
Everything works well but the last part of the code only work for the last sheet that the macro is reading. see below the code (I reduced the size for an easier understanding so between the irow = irow +1 instead of having 37 lines, there are only 1 or 2):

```
For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If Ws.Range("B1") = "ON" Then
    Ws.Select

    If Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 1).Offset(-1) <> Ws.Range("B9").Value Then
        Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 1) = Ws.Range("B9").Value
    End If

    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 2) = "abc"

    irow = irow + 1

    If Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 1).Offset(-1) <> Ws.Range("B9").Value Then
        Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 1) = Ws.Range("B9").Value
    End If

    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 2) = "def"

    irow = irow + 1

    If Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 1).Offset(-2) <> Ws.Range("B9").Value Then
        Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 1) = Ws.Range("B9").Value
    End If

    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 2) = "ghi"

    irow = irow + 1

    If Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 1).Offset(-3) <> Ws.Range("B9").Value Then
        Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 1) = Ws.Range("B9").Value
    End If

    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 2) = "jkl"

    irow = irow + 1

    If Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 1).Offset(-4) <> Ws.Range("B9").Value Then
        Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 1) = Ws.Range("B9").Value
    End If

    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 2) = "mno"

    irow = irow + 1

    If Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 1).Offset(-5) <> Ws.Range("B9").Value Then
        Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 1) = Ws.Range("B9").Value
    End If

    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 2) = "pqr"

    irow = irow + 1

    If Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 1).Offset(-6) <> Ws.Range("B9").Value Then
        Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 1) = Ws.Range("B9").Value
    End If

    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 2) = "tuv"

    irow = irow + 1

    If Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 1).Offset(-7) <> Ws.Range("B9").Value Then
        Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 1) = Ws.Range("B9").Value
    End If

    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 2) = "wxy"

End If
Next
```

So the last part after the last irow = irow + 1 is only happening for the last sheet that the loop is picking the values from.

If you are interested in the entire code see below:

```
Sub Generate_GP()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False

Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim irow As String
Dim lastrow As String

irow = Range("B2000").End(xlUp).Row

For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If Ws.Range("B1") = "ON" Then
    Ws.Select

    If Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 1).Offset(-1) <> Ws.Range("B9").Value Then
        Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 1) = Ws.Range("B9").Value
    End If

    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 2) = "P2 - Base Revenue"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 3) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$H$14"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 4) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$I$14"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 6) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$F$14"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 7) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$G$14"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 8) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$J$14"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 9) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$K$14"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 10) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$L$14"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 11) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$M$14"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 12) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$N$14"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 13) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$O$14"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 14) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$P$14"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 15) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$Q$14"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 16) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$R$14"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 17) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$S$14"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 18) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$T$14"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 19) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$U$14"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 22) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$W$14"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 23) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$X$14"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 24) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$Y$14"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 25) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$Z$14"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 26) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AA$14"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 27) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AB$14"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 28) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AC$14"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 29) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AD$14"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 30) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AE$14"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 31) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AF$14"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 32) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AG$14"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 34) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AH$14"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 35) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AJ$14"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 36) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AK$14"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 37) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AL$14"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 36) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AM$14"

    irow = irow + 1

    If Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 1).Offset(-1) <> Ws.Range("B9").Value Then
        Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 1) = Ws.Range("B9").Value
    End If

    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 2) = "P2 - Costs"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 3) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$H$15"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 4) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$I$15"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 6) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$F$15"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 7) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$G$15"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 8) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$J$15"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 9) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$K$15"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 10) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$L$15"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 11) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$M$15"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 12) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$N$15"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 13) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$O$15"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 14) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$P$15"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 15) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$Q$15"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 16) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$R$15"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 17) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$S$15"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 18) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$T$15"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 19) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$U$15"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 21) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$W$15"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 22) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$X$15"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 23) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$Y$15"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 24) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$Z$15"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 25) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AA$15"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 26) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AB$15"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 27) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AC$15"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 28) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AD$15"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 29) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AE$15"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 30) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AF$15"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 31) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AG$15"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 32) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AH$15"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 34) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AJ$15"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 35) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AK$15"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 36) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AL$15"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 37) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AM$15"

    irow = irow + 1

    If Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 1).Offset(-2) <> Ws.Range("B9").Value Then
        Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 1) = Ws.Range("B9").Value
    End If

    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 2) = "P2 - Base GP"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 3) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$H$16"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 4) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$I$16"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 6) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$F$16"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 7) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$G$16"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 8) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$J$16"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 9) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$K$16"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 10) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$L$16"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 11) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$M$16"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 12) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$N$16"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 13) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$O$16"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 14) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$P$16"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 15) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$Q$16"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 16) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$R$16"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 17) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$S$16"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 18) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$T$16"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 19) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$U$16"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 21) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$W$16"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 22) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$X$16"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 23) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$Y$16"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 24) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$Z$16"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 25) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AA$16"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 26) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AB$16"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 27) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AC$16"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 28) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AD$16"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 29) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AE$16"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 30) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AF$16"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 31) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AG$16"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 32) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AH$16"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 34) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AJ$16"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 35) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AK$16"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 36) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AL$16"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 37) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AM$16"

    irow = irow + 1

    If Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 1).Offset(-3) <> Ws.Range("B9").Value Then
        Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 1) = Ws.Range("B9").Value
    End If

    'B - P2 - Base Revenue
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 2) = "%GP"

    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 3) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 3).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 3).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 4) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 4).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 4).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 6) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 6).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 6).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 7) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 7).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 7).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 8) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 8).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 8).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 9) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 9).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 9).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 10) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 10).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 10).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 11) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 11).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 11).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 12) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 12).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 12).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 13) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 13).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 13).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 14) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 14).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 14).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 15) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 15).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 15).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 16) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 16).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 16).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 17) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 17).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 17).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 18) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 18).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 18).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 19) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 19).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 19).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 21) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 21).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 21).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 22) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 22).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 22).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 23) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 23).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 23).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 24) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 24).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 24).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 25) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 25).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 25).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 26) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 26).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 26).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 27) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 27).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 27).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 28) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 28).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 28).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 29) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 29).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 29).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 30) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 30).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 30).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 31) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 31).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 31).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 32) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 32).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 32).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 34) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 34).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 34).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 35) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 35).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 35).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 36) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 36).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 36).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 37) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 37).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 37).Address & ""

    irow = irow + 1

    If Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 1).Offset(-4) <> Ws.Range("B9").Value Then
        Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 1) = Ws.Range("B9").Value
    End If

    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 2) = "P5 - Variable Revenue"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 3) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$H$18"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 4) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$I$18"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 6) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$F$18"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 7) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$G$18"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 8) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$J$18"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 9) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$K$18"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 10) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$L$18"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 11) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$M$18"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 12) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$N$18"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 13) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$O$18"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 14) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$P$18"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 15) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$Q$18"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 16) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$R$18"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 17) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$S$18"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 18) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$T$18"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 19) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$U$18"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 21) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$W$18"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 22) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$X$18"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 23) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$Y$18"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 24) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$Z$18"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 25) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AA$18"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 26) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AB$18"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 27) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AC$18"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 28) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AD$18"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 29) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AE$18"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 30) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AF$18"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 31) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AG$18"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 32) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AH$18"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 34) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AJ$18"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 35) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AK$18"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 36) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AL$18"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 37) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AM$18"

    irow = irow + 1

    If Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 1).Offset(-5) <> Ws.Range("B9").Value Then
        Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 1) = Ws.Range("B9").Value
    End If

    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 2) = "P5 - Costs"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 3) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$H$19"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 4) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$I$19"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 6) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$F$19"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 7) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$G$19"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 8) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$J$19"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 9) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$K$19"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 10) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$L$19"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 11) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$M$19"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 12) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$N$19"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 13) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$O$19"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 14) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$P$19"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 15) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$Q$19"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 16) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$R$19"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 17) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$S$19"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 18) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$T$19"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 19) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$U$19"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 21) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$W$19"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 22) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$X$19"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 23) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$Y$19"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 24) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$Z$19"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 25) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AA$19"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 26) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AB$19"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 27) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AC$19"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 28) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AD$19"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 29) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AE$19"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 30) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AF$19"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 31) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AG$19"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 32) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AH$19"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 34) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AJ$19"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 35) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AK$19"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 36) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AL$19"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 37) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AM$19"

    irow = irow + 1

    If Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 1).Offset(-6) <> Ws.Range("B9").Value Then
        Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 1) = Ws.Range("B9").Value
    End If

    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 2) = "P5 - Variable GP"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 3) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$H$20"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 4) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$I$20"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 6) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$F$20"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 7) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$G$20"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 8) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$J$20"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 9) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$K$20"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 10) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$L$20"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 11) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$M$20"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 12) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$N$20"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 13) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$O$20"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 14) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$P$20"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 15) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$Q$20"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 16) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$R$20"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 17) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$S$20"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 18) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$T$20"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 19) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$U$20"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 21) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$W$20"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 22) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$X$20"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 23) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$Y$20"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 24) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$Z$20"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 25) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AA$20"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 26) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AB$20"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 27) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AC$20"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 28) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AD$20"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 29) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AE$20"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 30) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AF$20"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 31) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AG$20"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 32) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AH$20"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 34) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AJ$20"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 35) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AK$20"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 36) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AL$20"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 37) = "='" & Ws.Range("B9") & "'!$AM$20"

    irow = irow + 1

    If Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 1).Offset(-7) <> Ws.Range("B9").Value Then
        Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 1) = Ws.Range("B9").Value
    End If


    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 2) = "%GP"
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 3) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 3).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 3).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 4) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 4).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 4).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 6) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 6).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 6).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 7) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 7).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 7).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 8) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 8).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 8).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 9) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 9).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 9).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 10) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 10).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 10).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 11) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 11).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 11).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 12) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 12).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 12).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 13) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 13).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 13).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 14) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 14).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 14).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 15) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 15).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 15).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 16) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 16).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 16).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 17) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 17).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 17).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 18) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 18).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 18).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 19) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 19).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 19).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 21) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 21).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 21).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 22) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 22).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 22).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 23) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 23).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 23).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 24) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 24).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 24).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 25) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 25).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 25).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 26) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 26).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 26).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 27) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 27).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 27).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 28) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 28).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 28).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 29) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 29).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 29).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 30) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 30).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 30).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 31) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 31).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 31).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 32) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 32).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 32).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 34) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 34).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 34).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 35) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 35).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 35).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 36) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 36).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 36).Address & ""
    Sheets("GP").Cells(irow, 37) = "=" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 1, 37).Address & "/" & Sheets("GP").Cells(irow - 3, 37).Address & ""

End If
Next

Sheets("GP").Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it works for all sheets but for all but the last one you overwrite it because you don't increment `irow` after the last command (or before the first)

Edit: a bit more detail: `irow` is pointing to the last non-empty row. Before writing, you need to increment `irow` so it points to the first empty row, or the last row will be overwritten. At the start of the loop, you don't increment `irow` so whatever was in the last row is overwritten whenever the loop starts over. So you need to add `irow = irow + 1` at the start of the loop. (You could also have `irow` point at the first empty row and increment after writing, I'm basing this on how you initialized `irow`)

Your code can probably be shortened substantially, once it works you should head over to codereview. I'm on mobile now so I'm not going into that.

Side note: `irow` and `lastrow` are row *numbers*, so why use a string? `Dim` them as `Long` instead. (`Integer` is only 2 bytes in VBA so use `Long` which is 4 bytes).

Using strings as numbers is especially dangerous because the `+` operator concatenates strings (like the `&`) operator. So when doing `irow = irow + 1` you are lucky that VBA converts the string to a number data type, then does the addition and then converts it back instead of converting the `1` to `String` and appending it to the `irow` string.

Try `MsgBox "irow+irow=" & irow + irow` or something similar to see what happens ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did change the string into long. However, can you precise what you mean by incrementing irow after the last command?

Comment: @MAxSegura I added more explanation

Comment: many thanks for your help Increment irow was the solution. I am interested in understanding what you mean by heading over to codereview. How can I get my code shorter?

Comment: [Codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is another stackexchange site where you can get help improving your code (as opposed to stackoverflow where you get help fixing errors).